# php str_replace within a CSS file using custom {tags}

Tags: php, html, css, str-replace

I have a script that updates a CSS file based upon some user input from an html form.

The script performs a str_replace and searches the CSS file for "tags". eg-

```
html,body {
    background: {bgcolor} url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    color: {textcolor};
}
```

This works great but obviously breaks that CSS file. Originally it didn't matter but because of a new feaature in my project, I need to use that CSS file.

So I was wondering if there were any better alternatives to this? I was thinking maybe something like:

```
html,body {
    background: #fff /*{textcolor*/ url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    color: #fff /*{textcolor*/;
}
```

So I could then use the comment symbols within the tag as well which means my CSS file isn't broken. Only problem is how would I replace/remove the hex as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `preg_replace()`:

`preg_replace("/\3[\w\d]{3,6}\s\/\*\{textcolor\}\*\//", $str_hex_code, $str_css_file)`

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that you've already got the script in place which replaces the tags with their respective values, why not do something like this:

1: Create a `style.php` file which loads `style.css`

2: `style.php` uses your already created function to replace the tags with your default values

3: `style.php` sets the header as `header('Content-type: text/css');`

4: `style.php` echoes out the string that has been modified

Then rather than calling `style.css` throughout your script, call `style.php` instead.